# Can sums be multiplied?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

[image]

I was thinking this statement would be true, because the limits are the same. Is there something I'm missing that would make this statement false?

Comment: See Cauchy product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: Why do you think the limits would be the same?  Try it with some finite values and you will see very soon it is not true.

Comment: The answer is, yes, you're missing something, but it's something that I think a lot of people would likely miss if they didn't have much experience with summations. So I think this is a good question.

Comment: Thanks all, I found what I was missing–just had to try with some finite values like you said @fleablood

Comment: Try the finite case.  What happens.

Comment: If all the terms are positive, but $A$ and $B$ are finite, then it is never true

Comment: This is tantamount to asking if $(a+b)(c+d)$ and $ac+bd$ are the same. In general, they are not, because you are neglecting various other term-by-term multiplications.

Comment: Which limits are "the same"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: There are easy counterexamples with $a_n=b_n=0$ for all $n\ge 3$.

Comment: brilliant scott (as always!)

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $(s_n)$ be convergent, and let $(a_n) = (s_1, 0, s_2, 0, \ldots) , (b_n) = (0, s_1, 0, s_2, \ldots)$. Then $a_n b_n = 0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:
A = 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ...
B = 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ...

The sum of all A's is 1. The sum off all B's is 1. But the sum of all their products is zero.